# How to keep text on the pygame window for a decided amount of time

Tags: python, pygame

I have made a car game in pygame. When the car crashes into the sides or the falling block, I want to display a message on the screen that says, "YOU CRASHED". Right now it is displaying the message, but the message disappears before you can even read it. I have tried many things right removing the game_loop() and time.sleep(2) lines, which makes it work. The problem with doing this is that as soon as it displays the message, it ends the game instead of restarting it like I want to. The part where I say def message_display(text) is where I give the command to display the text. Here is the code for the game:

````
import time
import random

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

red = (200,0,0)
green = (0,200,0)

bright_red = (255,0,0)
bright_green = (0,255,0)


car_width = 86

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Racing Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

carImg = pygame.image.load("download.png")
carImg = pygame.transform.scale(carImg,(100,160))

def things_dodged(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render ("Dodged: "+str(count), True, black)
    gameDisplay.blit(text,(0,0))

def things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, [thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])

def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg, (x,y))

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",100)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

    game_loop()

    time.sleep(2)

def crash():
    message_display ("YOU CRASHED")

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action = None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    print(click)
    if x + w > mouse [0] > x and y + h > mouse [1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac, (x,y,w,h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            if action == "play":
                game_loop()

            elif action == "quit":
                pygame.quit()
                quit()


    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic, (x,y,w,h))

    smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText) 
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)


def game_intro():
    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",100)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Racing Game", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)


        button ("GO!",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,"play")
        button ("QUIT!",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red,"quit")





        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)



def game_loop():
    x = (display_width * 0.45)
    y = (display_height * 0.72)

    x_change = 0

    thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
    thing_starty = -600
    thing_speed = 7
    thing_width = 100
    thing_height = 100

    thingCount = 1

    dodged = 0


    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0

        x += x_change

        gameDisplay.fill(white)


        things(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height, black)
        thing_starty += thing_speed
        car (x,y)
        things_dodged(dodged)

        if x > display_width - car_width or x < -10:
            crash()


        if thing_starty > display_height:
            thing_starty = 0 - thing_height
            thing_startx = random.randrange(0,display_width)
            dodged += 1
            thing_speed += 1
            #thing_width += (dodged * 0.5)


        if y < thing_starty + thing_height:


            if x > thing_startx and x < thing_startx + thing_width or x + car_width > thing_startx and x + car_width < thing_startx + thing_width: 
                crash()

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(100)

game_intro()        
game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()```

If you guys can help thank you so much, but if you can't it's okay.
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `time.sleep(2)` before `game_loop()` in `message_display(text)`

```
def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",100)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

    time.sleep(2) #here the switch of lines
    game_loop()
```

If you call `game_loop()` before, you never put the game to sleep, you restart the game immediately and `time_sleep` is never called.

Comment: This didn't work. As soon as the car crashed it paused for 2 seconds, flash the message super fast, and start the game again. Thank you for your time, but if possible can you find another answer.

Comment: Strange, I tested the code and works for me. The message appears as soon as the car collides and remains on the screen for two seconds

Comment: I mean, I really swapped the `time.sleep(2)` line with the `game_loop()` line in that function and nothing else, and the program works (well, I also replaced the car with a red square because I do not have the car image, but this is irrelevant). Are you sure you still call `pygame.display.update()` before those lines?

Comment: Yes. I called pygame.display.update() before those lines and everything else is still the same as your code, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand why. Did you make any other change to the code with respect to what you have posted in your question?

Comment: No. Maybe you can post the entire code you tried and I can try that.

Comment: Have a try, but I really just swapped those two lines. https://pastebin.com/rRsKrxug

Comment: Yeah, it's giving me the same result as my code. Is it because I am running it in idle

Comment: open a terminal, and type `python myscript.py` where myscript.py would be the name of your script. Sometimes IDLE behave differently.

Comment: When I typed it in terminal responded, "can't open file 'myscript.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Comment: `myscript.py` would be the name of your file (do not know how is called on your machine).